# Why would I get a "-Infinity" result for $avg in an aggregate query?

Tags: mongodb

My aggregate query for retrieving "average percents per month" returns a `-Infinity` average for some months. What would cause this?

The relative properties in `mycollection` are `mydate` and `mynumericfield`, which stores a percentage value as a double.

```
db.mycollection.aggregate(
    [
      { 
          $match: { 
              mydate: { 
                  $gte: new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 8, 1)),
                  $lte: new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 12, 1)),
              } 
          } 
      },
      {
        $group : {
           _id : { month: { $month: "$mydate" }, year: { $year: "$mydate" } },
           average: { $avg: "$mynumericfield" },
           count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
      }

   ]
 )
```

Here's a sample of the result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "month" : 9,
                "year" : 2014
            },
            "average" : 84.2586640583996598,
            "count" : 20959.0000000000000000
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "month" : 11,
                "year" : 2014
            },
            "average" : 96.9326915103888638,
            "count" : 20743.0000000000000000
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "month" : 10,
                "year" : 2014
            },
            "average" : -Infinity,
            "count" : 20939.0000000000000000
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "month" : 12,
                "year" : 2014
            },
            "average" : -Infinity,
            "count" : 20913.0000000000000000
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to somehow reproduce the `-Infinity` problem but on a smaller scale.

Let's take sample collection `nums` having only 4 documents in it:

```
{ "_id" : 0, "grp" : 1, "mynum" : -Infinity }
{ "_id" : 1, "grp" : 1, "mynum" : 5 }
{ "_id" : 3, "grp" : 2, "mynum" : 8 }
{ "_id" : 4, "grp" : 2, "mynum" : 89 }
```

Performing simple aggregation on this collection like:

```
> db.nums.aggregate([{$group:{"_id":"$grp", "average" : {$avg : "$mynum"}}}])
```

gives the following result:

```
{ "_id" : 2, "average" : 48.5 }
{ "_id" : 1, "average" : -Infinity }
```

which is identical in effects to what you have experienced.

Please try to find out whether in your collection there is a document which has `mynumericfield` with value `-Infinity` - maybe your situation is similar to the reproduced one:

```
> db.mycollection.find({mynumericfield : -Infinity})
```

I hope it might help you some way.

Comment: Confirmed, there were infinite values in some of my documents. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. I'm really glad it helped :) It was very interesting issue :)